# PFQuery current user specific objects

Tags: ios, parse-platform

Hope anyone could help me to get this code working with Parse.com in iOS app.

I have a table that query Parse.com class called Channel with 5 main columns.

- One: "objectId"
- Two: "owner" which is a Pointer<_User(main class)>
- Third: "name"
- Fourth: "about"
- Fifth: "image"

   
   
  I  need to query to the table only the channels "name", "about" and "image" created specific by the current user.

   
   
  In my code the queryForTable method doesn't work when I try [query whereKey:@"name" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser].objectId](currently commented in the below). The current ACL for all the columns is Public Read.

My current code is as follows:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {


        self.parseClassName = @"Channel";

        //self.textKey = @"name";

        self.pullToRefreshEnabled = YES;

        self.paginationEnabled = YES;

        self.objectsPerPage = 5;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}


#pragma mark - UIViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];



}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    //self.canSearch = 0;

}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}



#pragma mark - Table view data source

//- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {//
//#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
// Return the number of sections.
//    return 0;
//}

//- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
//#warning Incomplete method implementation.
// Return the number of rows in the section.
//}





#pragma mark - PFQueryTableViewController



#pragma mark - Query

- (PFQuery *)queryForTable
{
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];
    //[query whereKey:@"name" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser].objectId];
    query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;

    return query;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    MyChanTableViewCell *cell = (MyChanTableViewCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell
    PFFile *thumbnail = [object objectForKey:@"image"];
    PFImageView *thumbnailImageView = (PFImageView*)cell.showImage;
    thumbnailImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image.jpg"];
    thumbnailImageView.file = thumbnail;
    [thumbnailImageView loadInBackground];


    cell.mainTitle.text = [object objectForKey:@"name"];
    cell.detail.text = [object objectForKey:@"about"];


    return cell;


}


// Set CellForRowAtIndexPath


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForNextPageAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *LoadMoreCellIdentifier = @"LoadMoreCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:LoadMoreCellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:LoadMoreCellIdentifier];
    }
    return cell;
}

// Set TableView Height for Load Next Page
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if([self.objects count] == indexPath.row) {
        // Load More Cell Height
        return 60.0;
    } else {
        return 80.0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are any of the values in the name column equal to an object ID?

Comment: Nope, the values in name column are string and there is the objectId column with its random values assigned by Parse

Comment: Hi @LyndseyScott thanx for the reply. Nope, the values in name column are string and there is the objectId column with its random values assigned by Parse

Comment: So if you query the name column for an object ID like you're currently doing, you're not going to find one.

Comment: Okay right @LyndseyScott my doubt is exactly that, which columns to query to obtain only the names related to current user, also how the query would be structured...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to output the `name` values for where `owner` is the current user, if I understand you correctly:

```
[query whereKey:@"owner" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
```

When comparing to a pointer, you compare the full object. The Parse SDK under the covers converts that to correctly comparing objectId values and object types, you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: Thnx @TimothyWalter the query works! Quite crazy how this happens in background. Despite all the Parse documentation this query its a PFRelational type ? To query a list of all other users there's no need to query relational, just query User class right ? Cheerzz

Answer (score 0):

As seems clear from your comments, you're not actually trying to query *using* the name; you're trying to query in order to retrieve the object's name *using* the objectID.

In your current `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, you're already accessing the `PFObject`'s name property. You don't need to (and can't) specify that you want a name from the query. The query will always return full `PFObjects`. You simply need to specify the proper column in which to search for the `objectID`...and this particular column is called "objectID" (not "name"), ex:

```
- (PFQuery *)queryForTable
{
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];
    [query whereKey:@"objectID" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser].objectId];
    query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;

    return query;
}
```

Comment: Thnx @LyndseyScott your explanation helped me to understand the separation of building the query and accessing the PFObject in table. Cheers!!!

Comment: Yep! ;)  Hope others too!

Answer (score 0):

```
 PFQuery *queryuser = [PFUser query];
    [queryuser whereKey:@"objectId" equalTo:[PFuser CurrentUser].objectId];
    [queryuser findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

        NSString *name = [objects valueForKey:@"name"];
        NSLog(@"%@",name);




    }];
```

Hope this will work for you.